# Google maps using python

Tags: python

I need to develop a tool (eg: calculate polygon area) and integrate it with Google Maps. I am not familiar with java. Can I do this using python? If yes, how can I go about integrating my code with Maps?

Answer (score 9):

You can do it, using **OpenStreetMap** instead of Google map, in **IPython/Jupyter Notebook**, through **ipyleaflet** package.
Just write(or import) your script in Ipython Notebook(a python based env.) and then take a look at here;

https://github.com/ellisonbg/ipyleaflet/tree/master/examples

you will be able to draw whatever you want defining new **Layer** and so on...

## Here an example:

#### Open your Ipython Notebook and import these modules;

```
from ipyleaflet import (
     Map,
     Marker,
     TileLayer, ImageOverlay,
     Polyline, Polygon, Rectangle, Circle, CircleMarker,
     GeoJSON,
     DrawControl
)

m = Map(zoom=0)
dc = DrawControl()
def handle_draw(self, action, geo_json):
    print(action)
    print(geo_json)
dc.on_draw(handle_draw)
m.add_control(dc)
m
```

#### The map will be appeared

[image: OpenStreetMap with drawing tools on the left hand side]

#### Zoom by double clicking on the your interesting spot, then draw your polygon using "Draw a polygon" item.

[image]

#### This is just a suggestion, you can use other methods to calculate the polygon's area

```
import pyproj    
import shapely
import shapely.ops as ops
from shapely.geometry.polygon import Polygon
from functools import partial
my_poly = dc.last_draw['geometry']['coordinates'][0]
geom = Polygon(my_poly)
geom_area = ops.transform(
partial(
    pyproj.transform,
    pyproj.Proj(init='EPSG:4326'),
    pyproj.Proj(
        proj='aea',
        lat1=geom.bounds[1],
        lat2=geom.bounds[3])),
geom)
print (geom_area.area, 'square meters, which is equal to',geom_area.area/1000000, 'square kilometers')
```

2320899322382.008 square meters, which is equal to 2320899.3223820077 square kilometers

Comment: Jupyter is giving the following error: 
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-20292c949459> in <module>()
----> 1 import ipyleaflet

ImportError: No module named 'ipyleaflet'

The package is installed

Comment: One way to achieve the given objective would be:
1. Open a map (openstreetmap / Google maps) and select points on the map which will be the vertices of the polygon
2. export the lat long of these vertices into a python code which will calculate the area of the polygon
3. Integrate this python code into the map so that the area which is the output of the python code is displayed on the map?

could you please be a little more elaborate on how this can be achieved using openstreetmap?

Comment: Sure you have to install ipyleaflet package first, as well as other necessary package and libraries. Look at the bottom of this page; github.com/ellisonbg/ipyleaflet For example if you are using Conda, just type the following in the command line: conda install -c conda-forge ipyleaflet I'll edit my naswer to show more clearly what I meant, hoping I got your question correctly.

Comment: Yes..Thanks a lot :) That was of great help